# Only allow a field to be edited and NOT written to in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

so I am trying to create a todo app using the Django rest Framework, and have my models.py as...

```
class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

What I want is that when a user inputs their task, I want the `completed` attribute to be hidden to the user and automatically set that to `false`. But then allow the user to change to true or false later on.

With my current serializer.py..

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('id', 'task', 'date_created', 'completed')
        extra_kwargs = {
            "date_created":{"read_only":True},
            # 'completed':{"read_only":True}
        }
```

And my views.py...

```
class ListView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.TaskSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, permissions.ViewOwnTask)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Task.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

In my serializer.py, the commented code `'completed':{"read_only":True}` allows the user to edit the field and write on that field when uploading, as shown in this image [image: here]

However when I uncomment the `'completed':{"read_only":True}` field, the option of writing the completed field disappears however I am not allowed to edit that field.

Is there anything such as `{"edit_only":True}`, allowing the user to edit the field only. If you get my point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

**EDIT**

My urls.py is...

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('task', views.ListView, basename='task')


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**2nd EDIT**

[image]

Hey @PrakashS now I get this kind of output which I don't want, I want only the `completed` field to be edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different serializers for adding and editing task:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from tasks.models import Task


class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'completed':{"read_only":True}
        }     

class TaskEditSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = '__all__'
```

And in views you can select serializer based on the add or edit view:

```
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView, ListCreateAPIView
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from .models import Task
from .permissions import IsOwnerOrReadOnly
from .serializers import TaskSerializer, TaskEditSerializer


class ListCreateTaskAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)


class RetrieveUpdateDestroyTaskAPIView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = TaskEditSerializer
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
```

urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ListCreateTaskAPIView.as_view(), name='get_post_tasks'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.RetrieveUpdateDestroyTaskAPIView.as_view(), name='get_delete_update_task'),
]
```

permissions.py file:

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.exceptions import PermissionDenied


class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow creator of an object to edit it.
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
        # so we'll always allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        # Write permissions are only allowed to the creator of the movie
        return obj.user == request.user
```

Comment: Hey, so I am still confused on how I should link it with my urls.py. And also whats the code in the .permissions for `IsOwnerOrReadOnly`. I shall upload my urls.py in my question now, please have a look at it.

Comment: Please see my updated answer for url patterns and permissions example. You can use your own permissions class anyway with this.